# How should i manage intro animation

Tags: animation

never realized how the animation intro of a game is done, I've thought that perhaps you have all the images of each frame of the animation, or have a video made and make the load.

anyway, if it is made of any of these ways,
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be quite common to play pre-rendered video files as cutscenes. But now that 3d engines became way more powerful, many games do their cutscenes with the game engine itself by replaying a scripted sequence. Playing cutscenes with the game engine has the advantage that it is less a break of immersion and also allows limited interactivity and character customization. It is also usually much cheaper to do. But when the game engine isn't designed for this, it can look quite awkward compared to a rendered video. Also, with rendered videos you can use a much higher level of detail, because you don't have to worry about the players machine being unable to render it in real-time with a proper framerate.

There was also a short phase in the late 90s where it became fashionable to film cutscenes with real actors. But this soon fell out of favor because the actors just looked too different from the 3d models representing the same characters during the actual gameplay.

There is never a *best* way to do something. There is only the best way for *you* and *your project*.

Comment: One advantage of rendering a movie once is that most computers these days decode videos on a dedicated chip, and there is much less work involved for the computer, so if you download the movie ahead of time, you can play it while the next level loads, use the movie to hide a load screen. If you use the game engine for cut scenes, you may have a problem where scene changes *cause* waits and load screens because you need to load an entirely new scene.